# Embedding a streaming audio page into an iframe

Tags: audio, iframe, embed

I am trying to figure out a way to embed a url that streams an audio stream to either an iframe of the best cross compatible browser frame that I could use. I would like to have it autoplay on mobile devices - which I would assume would be no issue as it's already streaming all the time anyway.

My stream url is

http://67.212.165.106:8028/stream

Thanks for any assistance with this, I tried to enclose this url in an iframe but it doesn't work.

Here's where I have that:

http://radio.baseballpodcasts.net/IframePlayer.html

Tried this and it doesn't seem to work:

http://radio.baseballpodcasts.net/IframePlayer.html

Answer (score 0):

You're linking directly to a stream so there's nothing to iframe.  What you need is an `<audio>` element.

```
<audio src="http://67.212.165.106:8028/stream" controls preload="none" autoplay></audio>
```

Note that `autoplay` does *not* normally work.  If users come to your site and click play often enough, it *may* eventually.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I see that it will work with the Safari browser, if you click the 'Play' button... it doesn't automatically stream the audio. In the Chrome and Edge browsers though it doesn't work at all, no auto stream, and doesn't work even when you click the 'play' arrow button.

Comment: https://radio.baseballpodcasts.net/IframePlayer.html

Comment: @RichBax You have an HTTPS page, but your audio is http.  That isn't going to work.  You need to find an HTTPS stream URL.